# How to change plist file

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have such problem: I have a plist file, which I made by adding it to recourse files from anothe project, now I can read it, but I don't now how to change it. Help me if you can, please.

Comment: do you want to add data to plist using code or something else ?

Comment: I don't want to add, just change existing information and save it back to plist file.

Comment: do you want to change it by code ?

Comment: please provide some code for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot directly write to our application bundle, so we need to copy our plist to our application's document directory for this use:

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourPlistName.plist"];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
{
     NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@”yourPlistName” ofType:@”plist”];

     [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error];
}
```

Then for editing the plist use:

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourPlistName.plist"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: plistPath ]) 
{
    NSMutableDictionary* infoDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    [infoDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:hidden] forKey:@"yourKey"];
    [infoDict writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
}
```

Here `yourPlistName.plist` is your plist and `yourKey` is the key for which you are setting a new value.

For more please check this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Oy-evy2xD8).

Comment: That's not going to work because you're trying to write to the original plist in the application bundle.  Applications can't write to the application bundle, they only have write access to a few other directories.